# Define component as constant

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

Im following a React Native course and at some point the teacher defines a component as constnat using the following code:

```
const Comment = (props) =>
  <Text>{props.text}</Text>
```

However I dont manage to make it work. I made a snack to just try the component individually and it doesnt work: https://snack.expo.io/S1eKSeV-7

I always get the error *Invariant Violation: element type is invalid.*

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not exporting your component. That is why you get the error because `Comment` component is undefined.

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import {Text} from 'react-native'

const Comment = (props) =>
  <Text>{props.comment.text}</Text>

export default Comment
```

Comment: @Rashomon updated answer. its should be `props.comment.text`

Comment: Oops.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This is a functional component. There are two type of components in React: Functional and class components. If you don't need any state or don't use any lifecycle methods in your component you can and should use functional components.

**Functional components**

```
const SomeComponent = () => <div>Something</div>;
```

No need to use an explicit return here since arrow function do this for us if there is one single statement.

With regular function:

```
function SomeComponent() { return <div>Something</div> };
```

**Class components**

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { foo: "bar" };
    someLifeCycleMethod() {
       ....
    }
    render() {
        return( <div>Something</div>);
    }
}
```

When you don't understand something always refer to [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

The problem you are having is not directly related to component type. As suggested in another answer your component probably is not exported.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
const Comment = (props) => {
  return (
    <Text>{props.text}</Text>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think this is exactly the same. Anyway, tried it an same behaviour